# Get elements between two or more indexes dynamically in Python without hardcoding number of index variables

Tags: python, list, indexing, nlp, nltk

I am trying to extract POS tags from an input text and extract all the words between 2 or more 'IN' tags. So, the idea is if there is 1 'IN' tag, the extraction happens from the index of the tag to the end of the sentence. If there are more than 2 'IN' tags, extraction should happen from the index of 1 tag to the other 'IN' tag, segregating the phrases into groups. I have written the code that does the same.
The code is :

```
def extractor(text):
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
#    print(pos_tagged)
#    Get tuple index of preposition
    indices = [i for i, tupl in enumerate(pos_tagged) if tupl[1] == 'IN']
#    print(indices)
    if len(indices) == 1:
        idx = indices[0]
        phrase = pos_tagged[idx:]
        words = [i[0] for i in phrase]
        comb_words = ' '.join(i for i in words)
        return comb_words 
        
    else:
        idx1 = indices[0]
        idx2 = indices[1]
        phrase1 = pos_tagged[idx1:idx2]
        words1 = [i[0] for i in phrase1]
        comb_words1 = ' '.join(i for i in words1)

        phrase2 = pos_tagged[idx2:]
        words2 = [i[0] for i in phrase2]
        comb_words2 = ' '.join(i for i in words2)
                        
        return comb_words1, comb_words2
        

extractor("hunger increases in the morning during workout")
```

and the output is as expected.
The only concern is that I have had to specifically hardcode the scenario if there are 2 'IN' tags in my text.
`idx1 = indices[0] idx2 = indices[1]`

So, this way, if there are 10 'IN' tags, I need to create 10 index variable in this way. Is there a better approach to solve this so that the index variables can be created dynamically based on the number of tags present in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a generator.

```
def extractor(text, tag='IN', max_level=None):
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    
    indices = [i for i, tupl in enumerate(pos_tagged) if tupl[1] == tag]
    
    # remove the first index if it is 0 -- we don't want empty phrase
    if not indices[0]:
        indices.pop(0)
    
    # maybe we don't care about tags past 2nd, or 5th, or 10th
    # indexing to None will just yield whole array
    indices = indices[:max_level] + [len(pos_tagged)]
    
    # the end of previous phrase
    prev_index = indices[0]
    
    for index in indices[1:]:
        words = pos_tagged[prev_index:index]
        prev_index = index
        
        yield ' '.join(word for (word, tag) in words)

list(extractor("hunger increases in the morning during workout"))
# ['in the morning', 'during workout']
```

max_level is for limiting the maximum number of tags you care about -- e.g., you want everything past the 5th tag to come in one piece regardless of tags, so you call `extractor(text, max_level=5)`.

EDIT: If you end up needing the part before the first tag occurrence, initialize the `prev_index` to `0` instead of `indices[0]`.

Comment: thanks for the approach. It works. Can you please suggest the code changes in my function based on the implementation

Comment: Well, you need to switch to a loop from a sequence of ifs. And in that loop use the idea in my solution -- i.e., `pos_tagged[idx1:idx2]` and then reassign indices `idx1, idx2 = idx2, new_index`. 
Still, what's stopping you from simply taking my solution?